# IE Issue: IE + MVC3 + Fineuploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I am having what appears to be an issue with Internet Explorer and it's default security settings for internet sites.

Im using MVC3 with [Fineuploader](http://Fineuploader.com)

When I try to upload a file it runs the onCompleate function but no files are uploaded and the response is null.

We identified that if the site is added to the "Local Intranet Sites" in Internet Explorer everything works fine. However if the site is left as an external site with default settings applied is not working.

Some code:

```
function createUploader() {
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
        //element: document.getElementById('uploadButton'), //$("#file-upload"),
        button: $("#file-uploader-basic").get(0),
        action: APPLICATION_ROOT + '/SharedWorkflow/UploadImg',
        params: {
            ImageID:        $('.imageShow').attr('data-ImageID'),
            testorderID:    $('.imageShow').attr('data-TestOrderID'),
            CaseNumber:     $('.imageShow').attr('data-CaseNumber'),
            Caption:        $('#newImgCaption').val()
        },
        debug: false,
        onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
            if ($("#file-uploader-basic").hasClass('fired') == false) {
                $('#file-uploader-basic').addClass('fired');
                $.blockUI({
                    message: 'Uploading image...'
                });
            } else {
                alert('You are currently uploading an image.');
                return false;
            }
        },
        onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            newImageName = fileName;
            debugger;
            $(".AddImage").attr('src', APPLICATION_ROOT + '/SharedWorkflow/GetImage?CaseNumber=' + responseJSON.Case.CaseNumber + '&r=' + Math.random());
            fillImageList(responseJSON.Image);
            $.growlUI('Image uploaded...', '');
            $('#file-uploader-basic').removeClass('fired');
        },
        onError: function (id, fileName, errorReason) {
            alert(errorReason);
        }
    });
}
```

Initially I thought it had to do with the Fineuploader component but after several attempts using different controller the same type of error is encountered when accessing the change method for input type='file'

Note : I have a project in ASP.NET working fine with Fileuploader from the Ajaxcontroltoolkit.

Comment: might be a server side issue, have you stepped through your server code to make sure it's not throwing exceptions and reaching the correct return statement? Perhaps post your server code.
I'm using the same stuff and I get the response back but IE9 prompts  to open the file so FineUploader doesn't seem to receive the response.
P.S. Make sure your success response is Json `{"success":true}`, to make that in C# you can do this:

`var success = new {success = true};`

`return Json(success);`

Comment: maybe this can help https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/readme.md#frequently-asked-questions-faq second question